# Select Sum of hours for specific month and year for specific user

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to realize a query where from DB with hours and dates I can select sum of all hours for certain department, in certain year.

Table example is the following:

[image]

So far the query which I am generating is the following:

```
    SELECT t.clientid, t.date, t.department, t.time,
                        (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) ) FROM time_management  WHERE YEAR(t.date)='$year' AND MONTH(t.date)= 12 GROUP BY t.clientid ) as january,
                        (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) ) FROM time_management  WHERE YEAR(t.date)='$year' AND MONTH(t.date)= 2 GROUP BY t.clientid ) as february
                        FROM time_management t GROUP by t.clientid
```

What I would like this to do is select sum of all hours for the month of January 2016. in the current state I am getting the result of sum of all hours for all clients and I would like to get result for client by client:

Current Result is:

[image]

So what I am searching for is how to get the sum of the times result grouped by `clientid` and get 2 results not only one. The sum for both client id. independently summed for each one of them ?

Any help will be very appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that without the subquery -

```
SELECT `date`, `department`, SUM(`time`)
    FROM `time_management`
    WHERE YEAR(`date`)='$year' AND MONTH(`date`)= 12
    GROUP BY `client_id`
```

I recommend you store you time in the database in seconds - the only time it needs to show as hours and minutes is when it's formatted to show on the client's screen. If you do store it as strings, you will have to put all that converting stuff back in.

Looking at it more, I'd also recommend storing your year and month either as separate columns, or as integers based on a pattern: 201612, perhaps, or something like that. That will clean up your where clause as well.

Comment: This looks like a very good solution, the reason for which I am using a sub query is to define it as month , in case if I have to dump 2 months or more like January , February etc.